# PHP & JQuery Photo Upload and Crop Issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using pre made code (http://www.jqueryrain.com/?ckQjAttu) to make a photo uploader and cropper. Obviously there code all works fine but all I want to add is: when the user selects a photo the form is automatically submitted. heres the current java script I am using to attempt this.

```
    <form action="my_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" 
    class="upload" name="upload">  
    <input name="image" size="30" type="file" id="file">  
    <input name="upload" type="submit" value="Edit Photo" id="upload">  
    </form>  
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('form.upload').on('change', function() {
   document.upload.submit();
   });  
   </script>
```

This does submit the form and takes the user to 'my_upload.php' and normally when the photo is uploaded it appears on the page. However when it is uploaded like this nothing appears at all!!

here is there php script ('my_upload.php') which have slightly edited for storing the photo and design of the page:

```
    <?php
    require 'core.php';
    require 'connect.php';
    /*
    * Copyright (c) 2008 http://www.webmotionuk.com / http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk
    * "PHP & Jquery image upload & crop"
    * Date: 2008-11-21
    * Ver 1.2
    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    *
    * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND 
    * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED 
    * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. 
    * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, 
    * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, 
    * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS 
    * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, 
    * STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF 
    * THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
    *
    */
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    session_start(); //Do not remove this
    //only assign a new timestamp if the session variable is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION['random_key']) || strlen($_SESSION['random_key'])==0){
        $_SESSION['random_key'] = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //assign the timestamp to the session variable
        $_SESSION['user_file_ext']= "";
    }
    #########################################################################################################
    # CONSTANTS                                                                                             #
    # You can alter the options below                                                                       #
    #########################################################################################################
    $upload_dir = "upload";                 // The directory for the images to be saved in
    $upload_path = $upload_dir."/";             // The path to where the image will be saved
    $large_image_prefix = "resize_";            // The prefix name to large image
    $thumb_image_prefix = "thumbnail_";         // The prefix name to the thumb image
    $large_image_name = $large_image_prefix.$_SESSION['random_key'];     // New name of the large image (append the timestamp to the filename)
    $thumb_image_name = $thumb_image_prefix.$_SESSION['random_key'];     // New name of the thumbnail image (append the timestamp to the filename)
    $max_file = "3";                            // Maximum file size in MB
    $max_width = "500";                         // Max width allowed for the large image
    $thumb_width = "100";                       // Width of thumbnail image
    $thumb_height = "100";                      // Height of thumbnail image
    // Only one of these image types should be allowed for upload
    $allowed_image_types = array('image/pjpeg'=>"jpg",'image/jpeg'=>"jpg",'image/jpg'=>"jpg",'image/png'=>"png",'image/x-png'=>"png",'image/gif'=>"gif");
    $allowed_image_ext = array_unique($allowed_image_types); // do not change this
    $image_ext = "";    // initialise variable, do not change this.
    foreach ($allowed_image_ext as $mime_type => $ext) {
        $image_ext.= strtoupper($ext)." ";
    }


    ##########################################################################################################
    # IMAGE FUNCTIONS                                                                                        #
    # You do not need to alter these functions                                                               #
    ##########################################################################################################
    function resizeImage($image,$width,$height,$scale) {
        list($imagewidth, $imageheight, $imageType) = getimagesize($image);
        $imageType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);
        $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
        $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
        switch($imageType) {
            case "image/gif":
                $source=imagecreatefromgif($image); 
                break;
            case "image/pjpeg":
            case "image/jpeg":
            case "image/jpg":
                $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($image); 
                break;
            case "image/png":
            case "image/x-png":
                $source=imagecreatefrompng($image); 
                break;
        }
        imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);

        switch($imageType) {
            case "image/gif":
                imagegif($newImage,$image); 
                break;
            case "image/pjpeg":
            case "image/jpeg":
            case "image/jpg":
                imagejpeg($newImage,$image,90); 
                break;
            case "image/png":
            case "image/x-png":
                imagepng($newImage,$image);  
                break;
        }

        chmod($image, 0777);
        return $image;
    }
    //You do not need to alter these functions
    function resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_name, $image, $width, $height, $start_width, $start_height, $scale){
        list($imagewidth, $imageheight, $imageType) = getimagesize($image);
        $imageType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);

        $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
        $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
        switch($imageType) {
            case "image/gif":
                $source=imagecreatefromgif($image); 
                break;
            case "image/pjpeg":
            case "image/jpeg":
            case "image/jpg":
                $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($image); 
                break;
            case "image/png":
            case "image/x-png":
                $source=imagecreatefrompng($image); 
                break;
        }
        imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$start_width,$start_height,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
        switch($imageType) {
            case "image/gif":
                imagegif($newImage,$thumb_image_name); 
                break;
            case "image/pjpeg":
            case "image/jpeg":
            case "image/jpg":
                imagejpeg($newImage,$thumb_image_name,90); 
                break;
            case "image/png":
            case "image/x-png":
                imagepng($newImage,$thumb_image_name);  
                break;
        }
        chmod($thumb_image_name, 0777);
        return $thumb_image_name;
    }
    //You do not need to alter these functions
    function getHeight($image) {
        $size = getimagesize($image);
        $height = $size[1];
        return $height;
    }
    //You do not need to alter these functions
    function getWidth($image) {
        $size = getimagesize($image);
        $width = $size[0];
        return $width;
    }

    //Image Locations
    $large_image_location = $upload_path.$large_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'];
    $thumb_image_location = $upload_path.$thumb_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'];

    //Create the upload directory with the right permissions if it doesn't exist
    if(!is_dir($upload_dir)){
        mkdir($upload_dir, 0777);
        chmod($upload_dir, 0777);
    }

    //Check to see if any images with the same name already exist
    if (file_exists($large_image_location)){
        if(file_exists($thumb_image_location)){
            $thumb_photo_exists = "<img src=\"".$upload_path.$thumb_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext']."\" alt=\"Thumbnail Image\"/>";
        }else{
            $thumb_photo_exists = "";
        }
        $large_photo_exists = "<img src=\"".$upload_path.$large_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext']."\" alt=\"Large Image\"/>";
    } else {
        $large_photo_exists = "";
        $thumb_photo_exists = "";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["upload"])) { 
        //Get the file information
        $userfile_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $userfile_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $userfile_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $filename = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $file_ext = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1));

        //Only process if the file is a JPG, PNG or GIF and below the allowed limit
        if((!empty($_FILES["image"])) && ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0)) {

            foreach ($allowed_image_types as $mime_type => $ext) {
                //loop through the specified image types and if they match the extension then break out
                //everything is ok so go and check file size
                if($file_ext==$ext && $userfile_type==$mime_type){
                    $error = "";
                    break;
                }else{
                    $error = "Only <strong>".$image_ext."</strong> images accepted for upload<br />";
                }
            }
            //check if the file size is above the allowed limit
            if ($userfile_size > ($max_file*1048576)) {
                $error.= "Images must be under ".$max_file."MB in size";
            }

        }else{
            $error= "Select an image for upload";
        }
        //Everything is ok, so we can upload the image.
        if (strlen($error)==0){

            if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
                //this file could now has an unknown file extension (we hope it's one of the ones set above!)
                $large_image_location = $large_image_location.".".$file_ext;
                $thumb_image_location = $thumb_image_location.".".$file_ext;

                //put the file ext in the session so we know what file to look for once its uploaded
                $_SESSION['user_file_ext']=".".$file_ext;

                move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $large_image_location);
                chmod($large_image_location, 0777);

                $width = getWidth($large_image_location);
                $height = getHeight($large_image_location);
                //Scale the image if it is greater than the width set above
                if ($width > $max_width){
                    $scale = $max_width/$width;
                    $uploaded = resizeImage($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
                }else{
                    $scale = 1;
                    $uploaded = resizeImage($large_image_location,$width,$height,$scale);
                }
                //Delete the thumbnail file so the user can create a new one
                if (file_exists($thumb_image_location)) {
                    unlink($thumb_image_location);
                }
            }
            //Refresh the page to show the new uploaded image
            header("location:".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
            exit();
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST["upload_thumbnail"]) && strlen($large_photo_exists)>0) {
        //Get the new coordinates to crop the image.
        $x1 = $_POST["x1"];
        $y1 = $_POST["y1"];
        $x2 = $_POST["x2"];
        $y2 = $_POST["y2"];
        $w = $_POST["w"];
        $h = $_POST["h"];
        //Scale the image to the thumb_width set above
        $scale = $thumb_width/$w;
        $cropped = resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_location, $large_image_location,$w,$h,$x1,$y1,$scale);
        //Reload the page again to view the thumbnail
        header("location:".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
        exit();
    }


    if ($_GET['a']=="delete" && strlen($_GET['t'])>0){
    //get the file locations 
        $large_image_location = $upload_path.$large_image_prefix.$_GET['t'];
        $thumb_image_location = $upload_path.$thumb_image_prefix.$_GET['t'];
        if (file_exists($large_image_location)) {
            unlink($large_image_location);
        }
        if (file_exists($thumb_image_location)) {
            unlink($thumb_image_location);
        }
        header("location:".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
        exit(); 
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta name="generator" content="WebMotionUK" />
        <title>Get Profile Picture</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_upload.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="

        jquery.imgareaselect.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
        <div class="image"> <a href="whosout.php"> <img class="logo" src="Logo.png"> </a></div>
        <div class="form">
        </div> <!--end of div form-->
        </div> <!--end of div header-->
        </header>
    <body>
    <!-- 
    * Copyright (c) 2008 http://www.webmotionuk.com / http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk
    * Date: 2008-11-21
    * "PHP & Jquery image upload & crop"
    * Ver 1.2
    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    *
    * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND 
    * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED 
    * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. 
    * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, 
    * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, 
    * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS 
    * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, 
    * STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF 
    * THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
    *
    -->
    <?php
    //Only display the javacript if an image has been uploaded
    if(strlen($large_photo_exists)>0){
        $current_large_image_width = getWidth($large_image_location);
        $current_large_image_height = getHeight($large_image_location);?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function preview(img, selection) { 
        var scaleX = <?php echo $thumb_width;?> / selection.width; 
        var scaleY = <?php echo $thumb_height;?> / selection.height; 

        $('#thumbnail + div > img').css({ 
            width: Math.round(scaleX * <?php echo $current_large_image_width;?>) + 'px', 
            height: Math.round(scaleY * <?php echo $current_large_image_height;?>) + 'px',
            marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px', 
            marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px' 
        });
        $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
        $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
        $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
        $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
        $('#w').val(selection.width);
        $('#h').val(selection.height);
    } 

    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#save_thumb').click(function() {
            var x1 = $('#x1').val();
            var y1 = $('#y1').val();
            var x2 = $('#x2').val();
            var y2 = $('#y2').val();
            var w = $('#w').val();
            var h = $('#h').val();
            if(x1=="" || y1=="" || x2=="" || y2=="" || w=="" || h==""){
                alert("You must make a selection first");
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        });
    }); 

    $(window).load(function () { 
        $('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:<?php echo $thumb_height/$thumb_width;?>', onSelectChange: preview }); 
    });

    </script>
    <?php }?>   
    <?php
    //Display error message if there are any
    if(strlen($error)>0){
        echo "<ul><li><strong>Error!</strong></li><li>".$error."</li></ul>";
    }
    if(strlen($large_photo_exists)>0 && strlen($thumb_photo_exists)>0){
        echo $large_photo_exists."&nbsp;".$thumb_photo_exists;
        $idPerson = getField('idPerson','person');
        $query = "UPDATE person SET pictureLocation = '".mysql_real_escape_string($thumb_image_name)."', gotData = '".mysql_real_escape_string('1')."' WHERE idPerson = '$idPerson'"; 
        if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){

        }

        //Clear the time stamp session and user file extension
        $_SESSION['random_key']= "";
        $_SESSION['user_file_ext']= "";
    }else{
            if(strlen($large_photo_exists)>0){?>
            <div class="allData">
            <div class="titleAndForm">
            <p id="title"> Upload a Photo</p>
            <p id="step"> Step 2/4 </p> 
                <img src="<?php echo $upload_path.$large_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'];?>" id="thumbnail" alt="Create Thumbnail" />
                <div style="display: none">
                    <img src="<?php echo $upload_path.$large_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'];?>" style="position: relative;" alt="Thumbnail Preview" />
                </div>
                <br style="clear:both;"/>
                <form name="thumbnail" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" id="x1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" id="y1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" id="x2" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" id="y2" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" id="w" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" id="h" />
                    <input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save Thumbnail" id="save_thumb" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php   } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- Copyright (c) 2008 http://www.webmotionuk.com -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any ideas on why The photo isn't submitted properly when it is uploaded by js would be amazing! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form using `form.submit` (`document.upload.submit();` in your case) the submit-button isn't included in your POST-data, so in your PHP the statement `isset($_POST["upload"])` equals to false.

So you need to change that condition, for example to `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {`. Or if you want to distinguish multiple forms add an hidden field and check on that (as it looks like because of your 'upload_thumbnail'-field).

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! So what you recomend is keep the js the same but add a submit button and edit the php code?